# Chained has_many through: users -> roles -> lists. Finding lists that a user is assigned to (via roles)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

It must be a very common problem. I have a chained many-to-many relationship like this:

User n<==>n Role n<==>n List

ActiveRecord models:

```
class User
  # linking to roles
  has_many :role_assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :role_assignments
end

class Role
  # linking back to users
  has_many :role_assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :role_assignments

  # linking to lists
  has_many :list_assignments
  has_many :lists, :through => :list_assignments
end

class List
  # linking back to roles
  has_many :list_assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :list_assignments
end

# ... and the join models:
class RoleAssignment
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :user
end

class ListAssignment
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :role
end
```

What would be a named_scope or an association in the List model to find all Lists that have all Roles that in their turn have a specific User?

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where are the role_assignments and list_assignments models?  You need the belongs_to declarations on the join table(s).

Comment: I omitted those for conciseness, but your question makes me think I should add them, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could come up with so far is the following:

```
class List
  has_many :list_assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :list_assignments

  named_scope :managable_by_user, lambda { |u| 
    role_ids = u.roles.map(&:id)
    {
      :include => [:list_assignments], 
      :conditions => {:list_assignments => {:role_id => role_ids}}
    }
  }
end
```